# Shredded cheese goes bad left out when...?

Tags: food-safety, temperature, cheese, spoilage, packaging

I had just bought three, 2 lb shredded bags of cheese.  Power outage while we were gone for 3 days.  Weather in area was very warm. Frig was never opened until our return, however it was not cold in the frig.  Is the cheese still okay to eat?  Looks okay, but not sure if safe to eat.

Comment: cheese will usually mold (which will be visible) rather than rot. That is something you can see and smell, so if it looks and smells fine I would eat it